# Jenkins Declarative Pipeline log a warning message that is visible in Blue Ocean

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

Is it possible to create a warning log message in Jenkins Blue Ocean view like the `unstable(MESSAGE)` warning message, but without setting the hole build state as unstable?

I mean the yellow/orange log message in this view "Couldn't load dependencies!":
[image: Example of unstable()]

`catchError(message: 'MESSAGE', buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'UNSTABLE')` will also not help, because the message is not visible in the Blue Ocean view.

Comment: Would it be OK to show stage result as "unstable" or is it required that only the message shows with yellow background?

Comment: That would be OK. A yellow message and a yellow stage result but a green build result.

Comment: There is `unstable` step, but this also marks the whole build as unstable. So I don't think this is currently possible (at least not straightforward, maybe through the jenkins/hudson API, I have not tried). I'm currently using `echo '\u26A0\uFE0F Some message'` for warnings which prints like "⚠️ Some message".

Comment: @zett42 thanks for the idea with the sign! But it's frustrated. I just want to create a simple warning message with the default Blue Ocean design. Why it exists not a method like `warning` to create this? Or a flag for the `echo` method? Hmm